# Get all sites of type "main_site"

Tags: support, api, sites

Is there a way to get all sites of type `main_site` from the `/site` method?

If not, what's the best way to get that list? Should I get all sites with a huge `pagesize` and then filter it in my App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [the sites path](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) does not filter results on `site_type`.  But the good news is, the path accepts a pagesize of `999`, so you can get all the results at once.

Then you must filter the results in your app.  Here's what it looks like in jQuery:

```
$.ajax ( {
    type:       'GET',
    url:        'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?pagesize=999&filter=!6ONhDO.aXP4LU&key=YOUR_APP_KEY',
    dataType:   'JSON',
    cache:      true,
    success:    processSiteListJSON,
    error:      function (err) {
                    alert ("Oopsie! " + err.responseText);
                }
} );

function processSiteListJSON (apiJson) {
    var mainSites = $.map (apiJson.items, function (siteDat) {
        if (siteDat.site_type == "main_site") {
            return siteDat.api_site_parameter;
        }
        return null;
    } );

    console.log ("Main sites are: ", mainSites.sort () );
}
```

Note that `meta.stackoverflow` is a special case and is considered a "main" site.

Comment: I think the API should allow filter in sites. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  You can open a feature request for such a filter/search. I doubt it will get approved, but it doesn't hurt to ask.